# Manually installing a Python library

Tags: python

I'm trying to install a particular python library (https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python/).

The recommended method is using pip, but pip doesn't work behind my university's authenticated proxy system. So I'm trying to install it manually. It has a setup.py file. I tried to do `sudo python setup.py install` and it said:

```
running install
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ appears to support .pth files
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing bitly_api.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to bitly_api.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to bitly_api.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'bitly_api.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'bitly_api.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bitly_api
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/bitly_api/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bitly_api
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/bitly_api/bitly_http.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bitly_api
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/bitly_api/bitly_api.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bitly_api
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bitly_api/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bitly_api/bitly_http.py to bitly_http.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bitly_api/bitly_api.py to bitly_api.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying bitly_api.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying bitly_api.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying bitly_api.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying bitly_api.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying bitly_api.egg-info/zip-safe -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
creating 'dist/bitly_api-0.2-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing bitly_api-0.2-py2.7.egg
removing '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bitly_api-0.2-py2.7.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bitly_api-0.2-py2.7.egg
Extracting bitly_api-0.2-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
bitly-api 0.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bitly_api-0.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for bitly-api==0.2
Finished processing dependencies for bitly-api==0.2
```

Which looks like a successfull installation. But then if I say `python` and then `import bitlyapi`, python says `ImportError: No module named bitlyapi`.

What am I doing wrong?

Btw I was following this guide: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/bitly-shortener-with-python/

Comment: Are you activated in a `virtualenv`?

Answer (score 2):

The name of the directory seams to be **bitly_api**.

So `import bitly_api` in python

Comment: The name of library can be found in the setup.py. It is in fact `bitly_api` https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: Chicken or the "egg" :-) http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html  Check the name='TowelStuff', however "from towelstuff import location"

Comment: Oh wow, how dumb of me. That guide has it wrong then, should've double checked.